# When using HBase, is it possible to store partitioned data in main memory of slave-node like IMDB (In-Memory DataBase)?

Tags: hbase, hdfs

[figure of system architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RPEG.png)

**Pre condition:**

- There are systems using `HDFS` based `HBase`.
- The tables managed by this system are `A`, `B`, and `C`.
- One `master node` manages n `slave nodes`.
- I want to distribute the data of table `B` and `C` to main memory of `slave node 1`, `slave node 2`, `slave node 3` rather than disk.

**Questions:**

[figure of HDFS Data Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X2KE.png)

- Q1. Is it correct to store the partitioned data of tables `B` and `C` in the `memstore` part of the `Rigional Server (slave node)` in the figure just above?
- Q2. Or is the contents of tables `B` and `C` scattered on the disk of the `slave node` collected and called into the main memory of the `master node`?
- Q3. I need a help to identify which is right in a `Q1` or `Q2`.

If I am misrepresenting the structure or relationship of the `master / slave nodes` of `HDFS` and `HBase` systems, or if I do not understand anything about them rightly, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> If I am misrepresenting the structure or relationship of the master / slave nodes of HDFS and HBase systems, or if I do not understand anything about them rightly, please let me know

Yes it seems that you are missing some fundamental HBase architecture concepts:

- 1 - This question does not make much sense. HBase stores the data on disk, and recent updates are stored in the memstore before flushed to disk. The memstore by itself does not reflect the data, just the recent changes. In order to get the data (as in `Get` command) the region server merges the persisted data with memstore data.
  **You** cannot "store" anything in the memstore - this is an internal component of the region server which you do not have access to (give or take some administrative operations).
- 2 - The master node is merely an administrative/manager node - it does not store nor serve any data. Only region servers do.